# How to POST new data via Ajax on React JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, asynchronous, http-post

Take in consideration this [example](http://codepen.io/teddarcuri/pen/EKWMvE)

I'm really new at React, so this is how I create my new app

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = { //initial empty details
      details : {}
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    //place the ajax call where ever you need
    $.ajax() //call ajax
    .done((data) => {
      this.setState({ //this setState will re render the UI with the new state
        details: { //change the key value pairs as needed
          id: data.id,
          trackInfo: {
            title: data.title,
            artist: data.artist,
            album: data.album,
          },
          trackUrl: data.trackUrl,
          albumArt: data.albumArt,
        }
      })
    })
  }
    render() {
      if(!this.state.details.id) return false //renders nothing when no details available
        return (
            <div id="app">
                <MusicPlayer
                    id={this.state.details.id}
                    visualizerType="RIPPLES"
                    theme={darkTheme}
                    trackInfo={this.state.details.trackInfo}
                    trackUrl={this.state.details.trackUrl}
                    albumArt={this.state.details.albumArt}
                    utilities={true}>
                </MusicPlayer>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

The plan is to create a button where on click it display a new MusicPlayer element. Eg.

```
<MusicPlayer
    id="3"
    visualizerType="RIPPLES"
    theme={lightTheme}
    trackInfo={{
        title: "Guns & Dogs",
            artist: "Portugal, The Man",
                album: "The Satanic Satanist"
    }}
    trackUrl="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/teddarcuri.monarch/Portugal.+The+Man+-+Guns+%26+Dogs+-+The+Satanic+Satanist.mp3"
    albumArt="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61X7CiBpZ6L.jpg"
    utilities={true}>
</MusicPlayer>
```

How can I proper POST new JSON data via Ajax to the render?

Comment: Please clean up the code. This looks like the output of Babel on ES6 code. If anything use that because as is it's pretty confusing what it is you're trying to do. Also what is wrong right now exactly? What is "proper" in your mind? It's very reasonable to make the ajax call in `componentDidMount` if that's what you're asking

Comment: Alright, getting past that, I see nothing wrong with the top code. What's wrong?

Comment: Agreed with @ZekeDroid why not post the original code? You'll get better help if you do.

Comment: @azium Ok thanks, I updated the question.

Comment: @ZekeDroid Thanks, I updated the question with the Babel code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your original ES6/JSX looks something like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            details: {},
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        $.ajax() // call ajax
        .done(data => {
            this.setState({ // this setState will re render the UI with the new state
                details: { // change the key value pairs as needed
                    id: data.id,
                    trackInfo: {
                        title: data.title,
                        artist: data.artist,
                        album: data.album,
                    },
                    trackUrl: data.trackUrl,
                    albumArt: data.albumArt,
                },
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MusicPlayer
                  {...{
                      id: this.state.details.id,
                      visualizerType: 'RIPPLES',
                      theme: darkTheme,
                      trackInfo: this.state.details.trackInfo,
                      trackUrl: this.state.details.trackUrl,
                      albumArt: this.state.details.albumArt,
                      utilities: true,
                  }}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and you want to make that $.ajax call again for some new player data on a button click. You need to create a method for the the click handler that can update the component's state.  This would look like:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            details: {},
        };

        // this is important so that the getNewData method will have the correct "this" context on click
        this.getNewData = this.getNewData.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        $.ajax() // call ajax
        .done(data => {
            this.setState({ // this setState will re render the UI with the new state
                details: { // change the key value pairs as needed
                    id: data.id,
                    trackInfo: {
                        title: data.title,
                        artist: data.artist,
                        album: data.album,
                    },
                    trackUrl: data.trackUrl,
                    albumArt: data.albumArt,
                },
            });
        });
    }

    getNewData(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // any logic to set up url or params for the ajax call can be done here

        $.ajax() // call ajax
        .done(data => {
            this.setState({ // this setState will re render the UI with the new state
                details: { // change the key value pairs as needed
                    id: data.id,
                    trackInfo: {
                        title: data.title,
                        artist: data.artist,
                        album: data.album,
                    },
                    trackUrl: data.trackUrl,
                    albumArt: data.albumArt,
                },
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MusicPlayer
                  {...{
                      id: this.state.details.id,
                      visualizerType: 'RIPPLES',
                      theme: darkTheme,
                      trackInfo: this.state.details.trackInfo,
                      trackUrl: this.state.details.trackUrl,
                      albumArt: this.state.details.albumArt,
                      utilities: true,
                  }}
                />

                <button onClick={this.getNewData}>Click me!</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This is a simple way to achieve what you want, but the data is localized to this component.  If you have a complex app you may want to do this with Redux and async actions or middleware, but that requires a more complex application setup.